# Generate bounding box from starting point (SVG)

Tags: c#, svg, graphics, computational-geometry, bounding-box

I need to generate a bounding box for shapes that are not guaranteed to be axis-aligned. Each shape has a point which designates their "front" on which the bounding box should have one face.

In a nutshell, this shape/bounding box:

[image]

Needs to end up looking something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the shapes themselves aren't transformed with their rotations, they're simply drawn that way, so all I'm left with is the singular point to try and determine where the bounding box should lie.

Any ideas on this one? If it's helpful to know, these graphics are defined in SVG and are being processed by a C# implementation using the vvvv/SVG lib on Github.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is called "Oriented Bounding Box" - if you want to search on that. It's fairly easy (and algorithmicly fast) to do this in 2D - much harder in higher dimensions. For 2D use [Rotating Calipers Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the face that the bounding box needs to align to, then you just need to:

1. Calculate the angle of that face to, say, the X axis
2. Rotate the shape by that angle so that the face is axis-aligned
3. Calculate the bounding box (min and max X & Ys)
4. Rotate the four bounding box corners by -angle.